# Laravel Model - Replace Current Values with Another Table While Serving

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've "products" table with; title, description, stock_code and image fields.

I've "product_pools" table also. And these two tables are matched with stock_code field.

But what I want is;

If product_pools matched with current product.
Then when i call product->title, i want to serve product_pools' table's title field. instead of products table.

And the same with description & image fields also.

I can use it like;

```
protected function title(): Attribute
{
    $pool = ProductPool::where('stock_code', $this->stock_code)->first();

    if($pool){
      return Attribute::make(
        get: fn (string $value) => $pool->title
      );
    }else{
      return Attribute::make(
        get: fn (string $value) => $value
      );
    }
}
```

But If I use this method, i'll use it on description & image fields also. And maybe more fields. Then it means: i'll make 3-4-5 queries in every model gettings. (and if im listing sth. its much worse).

How can I make this with only 1 query.
Whenever i call "Product", it'll connect product_pools and will serve its all values that i want to serve.

Answer (score 0):

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    public function pool()
    {
        // This might need to change based on your database structure
        return $this->hasOne(ProductPool::class, 'stock_code', 'stock_code');
    }

    public function title(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn (string $value) => $this->pool?->title ?? $value
        );
    }

}
```

```php
Product::query()->with('pool')->first()->title
```

This will make two queries, no matter how many products or product pools you have. 1 query for all products your selecting, and 1 query for all related product pools to all products selected

One to One relations: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Eager loading - prevent [N+1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/97253/10917416) issues: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

weird ?-> syntax: https://php.watch/versions/8.0/null-safe-operator

An alternative method is to join in the product pools table and select `DB::raw('COALESCE(product_pools.title, products.title) as title')` then you wont need the attribute or relation methods, but using raw sql can get messy fast

COALESCE: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp 
IFNULL: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_ifnull.asp